# Countdown Timer for every 6 hours

Tags: javascript, html, countdowntimer

Just wondering, if there is any way or codes, that can set countdown timer for every 6hours, for everyday?

For example, i want to start countdown at this timing(In other words, like every 6 hours):
9am-3pm
3pm-9pm
9pm-3am
3am-9am?

I have look all over the site, and couldn't find a countdown timer like that..

Preferably in HTML and javascript/jquery.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var timer = {
        started: false,
        timestamp: 0
    },
    trigger = 15;                          //3pm

function timerInit(){
    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    if(!started && hour === trigger){      //When it's 3pm, the timer will start
        startTimer();                      //└─ rewrite the conditional statement 
                                           //   as needed
        //do whatever you want here
        timer.timestamp = +new Date();
        timer.started = true;              //Indicates the timer has been started
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(timerInit);      //setTimeout is not efficient
}
requestAnimationFrame(timerInit);


//This is for when the timer has ended.
function timerEnded(){
    timer.started = false;
}

function startTimer(){
    var d = new Date();
    timePassed = new Date(timer.timestamp + 1000*60*60*6 - d);
    var remaining = {                      //Calculate time difference
        hour: timePassed.getHours(),       // using timestamps
        minute: timePassed.getMinutes(),
        second: timePassed.getSeconds()
    }
    console.log(remaining);
    if(timePassed > 0){
        setTimeout(startTimer, 500);       //Countdown
    }else{
        timerEnded();                      //Ended
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/kKPcr/7/

Comment: Thanks Derek! but may i know how to display the countdown in hours, mins and secs?

Comment: You want the countdown part too?

Comment: Yes please.. Need to display the countdown timer and it will keep repeating for every 6 hours.

Comment: @desmond - Maybe you should try it yourself first. Nevertheless I added the code.

Comment: i have tried, but cant seem to display the countdown timer? is it becoz, it have not been triggered yet?. Anw, please help me take alook at the code -> http://jsfiddle.net/kKPcr/1/

Comment: @desmond - Fixed the code for you: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/kKPcr/3/ It was because the jQuery onload stuff.

Comment: Thanks Derek! But how come is it, counting down from 7hours plus?? Sorry, i am very new to Javascript/JQuery..

Comment: @desmond - Because it is counting towards tomorrow's 3pm from the current time. This is happening because you manually started the countdown.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/kKPcr/7/ Here you go, whenever you start the timer, it will start counting from 6 hours to 0 hour.

Comment: Yeah, it is great.. But the countdown seem to reset each time, i refresh the browser.. Can the countdown be based on real time?

Comment: @desmond - It is supposed to be reset each time, because the timer should be started only when it is 3pm, 9pm...etc. I started it manually just to show it is working.

Answer (score -2):

You can use javascript's native `setInterval` method

E.g:

```
var timer = setInterval(myfunction, 21600) // 21600 seconds == 6 hours
```